# Why $(\log n)^k = O(n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

If I have $(\log_2(n))^{100}   $ , then what is $C$ and $k$,so that $(\log_2(n))^{100}≤ C\times n?$

I know that $(\log_2(n))^{100}   $ ≤ $n^{100}$, but I cannot find the $C$ and $k$ of $(\log_2(n))^{100}≤ C\times n$,since the leftside is always bigger than the right.

Comment: I have edited your question to make slight improvements in formatting. Please make sure that the idea of the original question hasn't changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $u\ge0$ we have

$$\log_2(u)\lt\log_2(1+u)={\ln(1+u)\over\ln2}\le{u\over\ln2}$$

It follows that

$${1\over100}\log_2(n)=\log_2(n^{1/100})\lt{n^{1/100}\over\ln2}$$

so that

$$\log_2(n)\lt{100\over\ln2}n^{1/100}$$

and consequently

$$(\log_2(n))^{100}\lt\left(100\over\ln2\right)^{100}n$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\log_2n$ Then (at least if $n\ge0$) $n=\exp(x\ln 2)=1+x\ln 2+(x\ln 2)^2/2!
+\cdots+(x\ln 2)^{100}/100!+\cdots$, so take $C=100!/(\ln2)^{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly based on limit; polynomially defined function is eventually surpassing $lg$ function starting from some value.